# How to filtered categories clicking on button and show result as higlithed links with jquery

Tags: jquery

I´m not so good with Jquery and I dont know how to solve this task.

I need to filtered data-categories for one Big shopping center, clicking and highlighted on buttons different categories to get highlighted links of shops as result.

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Work Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #eeeee9;
}
ul,li {
    list-style-type: none;
    
}
a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
    font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
}
.butikkvelger {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: 1px solid lightcoral;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.butikkvelger nav.kategorier {
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
   
    
}

.kategorier {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    display:block;
    position: relative;

}
.butikkvelger nav.butikker {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 180px;
}
.kategorier h2, .butikker h2 {
    
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 0 33px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.butikkvelger .kategorier h2, .butikkvelger .butikker h2{
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}


.kategorier li {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 33.33333%;
    padding: .25em;
}


.kategorier ul li:nth-child(2n+3) {
    clear: none;
}

button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-width: 0;
    font-family: 'Work Sans',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #373533;
    background-color: rgb(246, 246, 241);
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    
}

.kategorier button {
    font-size: 1em;
    min-height: 57px;
    padding-right: .625em;
    width: 100%;
}

.kategorier button:hover {
    background-color: #9D0A62;
    transition: all ease-out;
    color: #fff;
}

/*buttiker*/
.butikkvelger nav.butikker {
    background-color: #f7f7f2;
}
.buttiker {
    padding: 2em 1em;
}
.butikker li {
    width: 33.333334%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: 500px;
}

.butikker ul a {
    color: #373533;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.hover{
    color:#222;
}
```

```html
<section class="butikkvelger">
        <nav class="kategorier">
            <h2>
                <span>Velg kategori</span>
            </h2>
            <ul>
        
                <li>
                    <button data-category="hus-og-hjem">
                        <span>Hus og hjem</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
        
                <li>
                    <button data-category="restauranter">
                        <span>Restauranter</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
        
                <li>
                    <button data-category="sport">
                        <span>Sport</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
        
        
        
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="butikker">
            <h2>
                <span>Butikker</span>
            </h2>
            <ul class="">
                <li data-category="hus-og-hjem" class="">
                    <a href="">Home at Home</a>
                </li>
        
                <li data-category="restauranter" class="">
                    <a href="">Haugli Bakeri</a>
                </li>
                <li data-category="hus-og-hjem" class="">
                    <a href="">Skeidar</a>
                </li>
                <li data-category="sport" class="">
                    <a href="">MX Sport </a>
                </li>
                <li data-category="sport" class="">
                    <a href="">XXL Sport og Villmark</a>
                </li>
        
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>
```

This is what i would like to get.
Thanks

please see the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle:

https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/vrGjKX

```
$(".butikker li" ).hide();
$(".kategorier button").on("click", function() {
  $(".butikker li[data-category=" + $(this).attr("data-category") + "]").show();
  $(".butikker li[data-category!=" + $(this).attr("data-category") + "]").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhumi Shah, when I use your code it is filtrering it´is working but how to get back all links.

Comment: Can you please write cod for that? 
Thanks!

Comment: ...i dont why but, when i refresh page all list with shops(links) are gone.
Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: you mean butikker list?

Answer (score 0):

@Bane, try with given solution and let me know  is it the same you expect?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".catName").hover(function(){
       $('.ulCatSub > li').hide();
        $("ul").find("li[data-category='" + $(this).data("category") +"']").css( "display", "block" )}, function(){
        if(!$(".catName").hasClass("active"))
        { 
          $('.ulCatSub > li').show();
        }
        else{
          var catName=  $(".active").data("category");
           $('.ulCatSub > li').hide();
        $("ul").find("li[data-category='" + catName +"']").css( "display", "block" );
        }
 });
 
 
 
    $(".catName").click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
        $(".catName").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $('.ulCatSub > li').hide();
        $("ul").find("li[data-category='" + $(this).data("category") +"']").css( "display", "block" );
        
    });
     $('.divBody').click(function(e){
 
        })   
        
        $(window).click(function() {
 $(".catName").removeClass("active");
             $('.ulCatSub > li').show();
});
});
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Work Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #eeeee9;
}
ul,li {
    list-style-type: none;
    
}
a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
    font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
}
.butikkvelger {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: 1px solid lightcoral;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.butikkvelger nav.kategorier {
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
   
    
}

.kategorier {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    z-index:999;

}
.butikkvelger nav.butikker {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 180px;
}
.kategorier h2, .butikker h2 {
    
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 0 33px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.butikkvelger .kategorier h2, .butikkvelger .butikker h2{
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}


.kategorier li {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 33.33333%;
    padding: .25em;
    z-index:9999;
}


.kategorier ul li:nth-child(2n+3) {
    clear: none;
}

button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-width: 0;
    font-family: 'Work Sans',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #373533;
    background-color: rgb(246, 246, 241);
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    
}

.kategorier button {
    font-size: 1em;
    min-height: 57px;
    padding-right: .625em;
    width: 100%;
}

.kategorier button:hover {
    background-color: #9D0A62;
    transition: all ease-out;
    color: #fff;
}

.active{
background-color: #9D0A62;
    transition: all ease-out;
    color: #fff;
}

/*buttiker*/
.butikkvelger nav.butikker {
    background-color: #f7f7f2;
}
.buttiker {
    padding: 2em 1em;
}
.butikker li {
    width: 33.333334%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: 500px;
}

.butikker ul a {
    color: #373533;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.hover{
    color:#222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="butikkvelger">
        <nav class="kategorier">
            <h2>
                <span>Velg kategori</span>
            </h2>
            <ul >
                <li>
                    <button class="catName" data-category="hus-og-hjem">
                        <span>Hus og hjem</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="catName" data-category="restauranter">
                        <span>Restauranter</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="catName" data-category="sport">
                        <span>Sport</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="butikker">
            <h2>
                <span>Butikker</span>
            </h2>
            <ul class="ulCatSub">
                <li data-category="hus-og-hjem" class="">
                    <a href="">Home at Home</a>
                </li>
        
                <li data-category="restauranter" class="">
                    <a href="">Haugli Bakeri</a>
                </li>
                <li data-category="hus-og-hjem" class="">
                    <a href="">Skeidar</a>
                </li>
                <li data-category="sport" class="">
                    <a href="">MX Sport </a>
                </li>
                <li data-category="sport" class="">
                    <a href="">XXL Sport og Villmark</a>
                </li>
        
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thanks

..but how to get all list of shops again? ..after clicking on buttons

Comment: use $('.ulCatSub > li').show() with button click event.On which you want to display all items. Let me know you need help in this case.

Comment: So write know I can´t get full list of items, only when i refresh the page.


Please can you write full code when you click off to display all items.

Comment: I tried like that:

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ulCatSub > li').hide();
    $(".catName").click(function () {
        $('.ulCatSub > li').hide();
        $("ul").find("li[data-category='" + $(this).data("category") + "']").css("display", "block");
    });
    $('.ulCatSub > li').show();
    $('.ulCatSub > li').click(function(){

    });
});

Comment: can you please elaborate more on which button click you want to display all item?

Comment: Ok, I wil try to explain better. First time when user come on website he/she will see all categories and all shops displayed on left div.

Selecting one categories will shows only shops  in that categories. Now I want to see again all shops (butikker li) again clicking with mouse outside from buttons. 
How to see again all shops links? clicking outside from buttons?
Hope this is more clear?

Comment: All shops (butikker li)should displayed on the right div again
Please see these site here to be more clear

https://tvedtsenteret.no/

Comment: @Bane I edit my answer, It works same as your given link i.e tvedtsenteret.no . If you click outside then all list will be rebind again. Check and let me know now its working as per your Expectation ?

Comment: Thanks @Priyal it is much better now. But I still have small issue. 
Can we fixed that when you click anywhere outside then all list will be rebind again. Have a look on website I m working now: http://www.raglamyrsenteret.no/

Comment: It is working! Thank you so much Priyal!You are awesome!. I would like to put red color on selected links after filtering categories (butikker li)  you  can see on image above :
Is it possible to do that on this line of code:

$("ul").find("li[data-category='" + $(this).data("category") +"']").css( "display", "block" );

$("ul").find("li[data-category='" + $(this).data("category") +"']").css( 
"display" : "block"
'font-size' : '10px',
"color": ##9D0A62;

Comment: Sorry Priyal but there is one more issue. Links doesn't works. 

When you click on the shop list (right div) and when you select one of the shop you cant move on to shop-page...Pls see on http://www.raglamyrsenteret.no/

Comment: I fixed:) Everything is fine! 
May I ask you (last question)if I want to filtered categories but this time to hover links on selected categories list it is the same process of coding as you write above just to change hover methods...Sorry I m beginner :)

Thanks a lot and i really appreciated your help!
Regards Bane

Comment: @ban, I edit my answer now check it. and let me know

Comment: @Priyal...Only one problem I founded is  when you select one item after filtering categories and click on link to see shop-page, first shows all shop list (butikker li) and than you proced to shop-page. 

Is it possible to proceed directly to clicked shop-page? ...instead to first see all shops(or disabled somehow) and than continue to clicked selected shop links.

Comment: Please see here: http://www.raglamyrsenteret.no/

Just try to open shop page..

Thanks!

Comment: @ban , https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp you can found each functionality related to javascript here. For beginner its very useful. I think you found many of your answer from here :)

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you so much!